# Stick image to the top of footer in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put an image on top of the footer, but my image is lying somewhere in the middle of the screen. I have tried `vertical-align`, wokaround using margin, but no success yet.

Here's  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InsaneCoder/mttovzr5/2/)

Here's my HTML structure,

```
<body id="extranav">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" ></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="link1.php">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="link2.php">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>     

    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
   <br><br>
   <div class="text-center">
     <a href="#" class="fa icon fa-facebook fa-lg"></a>
     <a href="#" class="fa icon fa-twitter fa-lg" ></a>
     <a href="#" class="fa icon fa-google fa-lg"></a>
     <br><br>
     <div class="footer-links">&nbsp;
      <a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="about-us.php">AboutUs</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="faq.php">FAQ</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <p>&copy; All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the CSS

```
html,body 
{
    height: 100%;
    /*font-size: 15pt;*/
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 1024px;
}
.footer
{
    background-color: #2D3339;
    color: white;
}
.footer a
{
    line-height: 2.8em;
}
.footer-links a,.footer-links p
{
    color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -200px;
}
.footer, .push {
height: 200px;
font-size: 15px;
}
.push
{
    background: url("http://i564.photobucket.com/albums/ss86/ban0107/aya/footer.gif") repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;   
}
```

Comment: This Ex. may helpful,

    <div style="bottom: 20px; position: absolute">
    </div>
,
you can also use left: px; or right: px; for set align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put the footer image `div` directly inside the footer? It will naturally fall right above the footer that way, then you just need to adjust the CSS so that the footer is 400px tall(200px for the image and 200px for the footer section below the image):

```
.footer
{
    height:400px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color:#2D3339;
    color:white;
}
.push
{
    height:200px;
    background:url("http://i564.photobucket.com/albums/ss86/ban0107/aya/footer.gif") repeat-x scroll center bottom;   
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mttovzr5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [**like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbrvrhhn/)

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="push"></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="text-center">
        <a href="#" class="fa icon fa-facebook fa-lg"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa icon fa-twitter fa-lg"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa icon fa-google fa-lg"></a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="footer-links">
            &nbsp;
      <a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="about-us.php">AboutUs</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="faq.php">FAQ</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <p>&copy; All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -400px;
}
.footer {
    height: 400px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.push
{
    height:200px;
    background:   url("http://i564.photobucket.com/albums/ss86/ban0107/aya/footer.gif") repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;   
}
```